# react-native-navigation with context api (react 16.3)

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

has anybody being able to use the new Context API introduce in react 16.3 with react-native-navigation?

I'm having trouble trying to set it up as with react-native-navigation there is no main component where i can manage a state and then render the Context.Provider components, just the Navigation.startSingleScreenApp or similar functions.

Tks in advance for any help you can provide

Environment
React Native Navigation version: 1.1.403
React Native version: 0.55.4
Platform(s): iOS
Device info : Simulator

Comment: Question is similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51187582/how-should-the-new-context-api-work-with-react-native-navigator

Answer (score 0):

Please update your question with the simplest code example that shows your problem.

Generally, you can wrap your  for example outside or inside whatever is your .

Maybe see this guide https://medium.com/@505aaron/a-practical-react-native-problem-solved-with-the-context-api-eecaf2e05202 for a simple enough example that does create a custom Context Provider/Consumer pair that also has its own state.

Answer (score 0):

react-native-navigation with Context API is not possible. there are some workarounds (https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation/issues/3549#issuecomment-411800487) but it is not the real React Context API behavior. (https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation/issues/3549#issuecomment-427603125)