# How to share globally in the app the state of a class component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am new to React Native, I am trying to change the state of an arithmetic function in a class component located in one screen and then share it globally in order to use it in different screens and possibly change it, what are some of the ways in which I can do this?

Comment: Maybe react-redux can help ypu ?

Comment: You can use [context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) API or other state management library like [Redux](https://redux.js.org/introduction/getting-started)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either [lift the state up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) or [use context API](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html)

also maybe you should consider using React Hooks

maybe this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44227235/global-state-in-react-native) is similar to your issue

also, these articles could help with the context [1](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2020/01/introduction-react-context-api/), [2](https://codeburst.io/global-state-with-react-hooks-and-context-api-87019cc4f2cf)

Comment: I am using React Navigation to navigate through my bottom tab navigator, is it possible to use context API with it?

Comment: the context API has nothing to do with react-navigation it is a React API so it should work with react and react-native. you can check these: 

1- [How to Use the React Context API to Build React Native, Expo, and Firebase Apps](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/how-to-use-the-react-context-api-to-build-react-native-expo-and-firebase-apps-adda840e52b0)
2- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51187582/how-should-the-new-context-api-work-with-react-native-navigator